# Como comparar array em python em uma lista de array e devolvendo o array igual ou o mais próximo

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist, algoritmo-de-busca, numpy

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para entrar com um vetor e procurar em uma lista de vetores qual é o que tem mais valores iguais ou parecidos utilizando Python.

Exemplo:

Eu tenho o seguinte vetor:

```
search = [-50,-68,-70,-65,-78,-55]
```

E quero saber com qual dos vetores abaixo ele é mais próximo ou idêntico

```
B1A = [-46,-78,-72,-70,-81,-59]
B1B = [-100,-82,-85,-100,-76,-55]
B1C = [-100,-100,-100,-78,-100,-58]
B4A = [-77,-100,-84,-75,-72,-72]
B4B = [-78,-81,-80,-72,-70,-67]
B4C = [-76,-76,-81,-67,-62,-67]
B5A = [-100,-76,-80,-67,-61,-69]
B5B = [-100,-79,-80,-68,-59,-71]
B6A = [-77,-81,-78,-62,-76,-80]
B6B = [-68,-75,-76,-54,-73,-74]
B6C = [-72,-73,-72,-62,-72,-75]
B7A = [-100,-78,-78,-65,-74,-78]
B7B = [-100,-81,-77,-69,-74,-76]
```

Eu fiz o seguinte com a ajuda do @JeanExtreme002

```
search = [-50,-78,-70,-65,-80,-55]

B1A = [-46,-78,-72,-70,-81,-59]
B1B = [-100,-82,-85,-100,-76,-55]
B1C = [-100,-100,-100,-78,-100,-58]
B2A = [-100,-88,-100,-100,-100,-60]
B2B = [-100,-78,-79,-80,-80,-59]
atual = ([], 0,'')

for vetor in [B1A, B1B, B1C, B2A, B2B]:
    quantidade = 0

    for valor in search:
        if valor in vetor:
            quantidade += 1

    if quantidade > atual[1]:
        atual = [vetor, quantidade]

resultado = atual[0]
matchs = atual[1]

print("Busca: {}".format(search))
print("Resultado: {}".format(resultado))
print("Matchs: {}".format(matchs))
```

**Porque este caso não me atende?**

Porque quando ele faz

```
for valor in search:
       if valor in vetor:
           quantidade += 1
```

Na verdade ele está verificando se existe aquele valor no vetor, mas eu preciso que cada valor seja comparado. ou seja, `search[0]` com `vetor[0]` e assim por diante.

A margem de erro pode ser entre 5 pra mais ou pra menos. ou seja: se o valor que busco no vetor for -55 quer dizer que eu aceito até -60 ou -50. O que estiver mais próximo.

Vi algo sobre essa função
`np.allclose(A,B,...)`
onde defino uma média de erro no array e ele devolve o valor mais próximo

Porém não sei se atende meu caso.

Mais um detalhe:

Se minha lista for `[-55, -75]` eu daria preferência para `[-54, -74]` pois se trata de uma tabela de força do sinal wireless então quanto menor, melhor.

Para corrigir questão de valores nulos eu substitui os `None` por `-100`

Bom, conto com a ajuda de todos! Obrigado desde já

Comment: Se a lista for `[-55, -75]`, qual é mais próximo: `[-54, -74]`, `[-56, -76]`, `[-54, -76]` ou `[-56, -74]`? Ou todos são igualmente próximos? Outra coisa, limite a pergunta a apenas uma linguagem (de preferência a que vc usou nas tags, ou seja, no caso seria apenas Python), senão ela pode acabar ficando ampla demais (e isso é [motivo de fechamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)). Além disso, `np.allclose` não retorna o valor mais próximo, e sim `True` ou `False` indicando se os arrays são "iguais" (dentro de uma margem de tolerância)

Comment: Bom, vamos la! Se minha lista for ```[-55, -75]``` eu daria preferência para ```[-54, -74]``` pois se trata de uma tabela de força do sinal wireless então quanto menor, melhor.

Sobre o ```np.allclose()``` eu sei que ele retorna true ou false mas eu poderia adaptar algo para ajustar no meu caso? ou teria alguma outra função parecida?

Comment: Então edite a pergunta e coloque essa informação na pergunta, pois aqui a regra é responder pelo que está na pergunta e não nos comentários, pois os comentários são considerados descartáveis e a qualquer momento podem serem removidos.

Comment: Peterson, como já disse o @AugustoVasques, por favor edite a pergunta e coloque todos os critérios lá, assim as pessoas não precisam "caçar" informações nos comentários (todas as informações relevantes devem estar no corpo da pergunta). Se bem que `-54` é **maior** que `-55`, então seu critério ("quanto menor, melhor") continua confuso pra mim. Também não ficou claro o que fazer se os arrays tiverem tamanhos diferentes (pode acontecer? há garantia que não acontece?), e o que considerar quando tem nulos: `[-55, -75]` é mais próximo de `[None, -74]` ou de `[-54, None]`?

Comment: Quanto a ter alguma função parecida, eu não conheço o `numpy` tão bem assim, então sugiro ver na [documentação](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.17.0/reference/) se já existe algo parecido com o que vc precisa...

Comment: Corrigi para ficar mais claro (e mais fácil) em vez de valores ```None``` substitui por ```-100```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi da sua pergunta: você quer comparar elemento-elemento um vetor referência 'search' com uma série de vetores B's e localizar aqueles que atendam a sua margem de erro para todos os elementos. Da para fazer isso sem usar loops com funções do numpy.

```
import numpy as np
search = np.array([(-50,-68,-70,-65,-78,-55)])

B1A = np.array([(-46,-78,-72,-70,-81,-59)])
B1B = np.array([(-100,-82,-85,-100,-76,-55)])
B1C = np.array([(-100,-100,-100,-78,-100,-58)])
B1D = np.array([(-51,-64,-73,-67,-79,-56)])
B4A = np.array([(-77,-100,-84,-75,-72,-72)])
B4B = np.array([(-78,-81,-80,-72,-70,-67)])
B4C = np.array([(-76,-76,-81,-67,-62,-67)])
B5A = np.array([(-100,-76,-80,-67,-61,-69)])
B5B = np.array([(-100,-79,-80,-68,-59,-71)])
B6A = np.array([(-77,-81,-78,-62,-76,-80)])
B6B = np.array([(-68,-75,-76,-54,-73,-74)])
B6C = np.array([(-72,-73,-72,-62,-72,-75)])
B7A = np.array([(-100,-78,-78,-65,-74,-78)])
B7B = np.array([(-100,-81,-77,-69,-74,-76)])

candidatos = [B1A, B1B, B1C, B1D, B4A, B4B, B4C, B5A, B5B, B6A, B6B, B6C, B7A, B7B]
margem_erro = 5.0

distancias = candidatos[::] - search # Avalia a distância de cada vetor para o vetor de busca.
avaliar_dist = np.where(np.absolute(distancias) < margem_erro, True, False) # Localiza em quais posições dos vetores de distância a margem de erro é satisfeita.
vetores_aprovados = avaliar_dist.all(axis=2) # Marca Verdadeiro se toda a linha tem valores Verdadeiros.
posicao_aprovados = np.array(np.where(vetores_aprovados== True)[0]) # Grava a posição dos vetores dentro da margem de erro.

print("Busca: {}".format(search))
print("Resultado: ")
for x in posicao_aprovados:
    print(candidatos[x])
```

Comment: Cara isso resolveu! Eu fiz uns testes e obtive os resultados esperados. Para isso só precisei calibrar a margem de erro (como esperado né) Muito obrigado!